# Postgresql -how to create condition based on total number of unique rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, rows

My goal is to create a condition where the number of unique rows equals 3 or more,

For an instance - if I got the result:

```
| id | 
1
2
3
```

then there are 3 rows return true. (for the existence part I'll use `EXISTS`)

I've tried to use `COUNT(*)` and `DISTINCT` to count all the different unique rows, but as I want to use condition -

- using `WHERE` is impossible due the `COUNT` function
- nor using `HAVING` - because there's a need to use `GROUP BY` first, which cause the `COUNT(*)=1`.

Another requirement - is to use postgresql at version 9.4

My latest attempt which returns nothing because `COUNT(*)=1`

```
exists(
     select count(*)
     from (select sid, bno
           from schedule scj inner join revent on scj.eid = revent.reid
           where 12345 = cno AND 'hello' = sid) as foo
     group by sid, bno
     having count(*)>=3)
```

Comment: what result do you want?   different rules apply to conditions in different contexts.

Comment: The result I was looking for on this question was a boolean value, 
as my final query is more complex than that, therefore - I was trying to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use:

```
select (count(*) >= 3)
from result;
```

`result` could be a CTE, subquery, or other query logic that generates the rows in your first result set.

So, if this is your query:

```
select sid, bno
from schedule scj inner join revent on scj.eid = revent.reid
where 12345 = cno AND 'hello' = sid
```

Then the logic is:

```
select (count(*) >= 3)
from (select sid, bno
      from schedule scj inner join revent on scj.eid = revent.reid
      where 12345 = cno AND 'hello' = sid
     ) result;
```

Comment: Look like it works, good to know there also conditions on the `SELECT` section, Thanks!